# linux cc error 'does not name a type'

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

I am trying to create a program which reads and writes buffer sizes, but without standard libraries. so far, I have written a main with header files, however whenever I compile my main, I keep getting errors,such as

```
In file included from main.cc:6:0:
DefaultClock.cpp: In member function ‘double AccurateClock::Time::getTotalMilliseconds() const’:
DefaultClock.cpp:10:14: error: ‘milliseconds’ does not name a type
         auto milliseconds =
              ^
DefaultClock.cpp:13:16: error: ‘milliseconds’ was not declared in this scope
         return milliseconds;
                ^
```

and so on for the next 30+ lines. Kind of stuck here, what could be the cause of the errors? I have the classes defined.

```
    #include "DefaultClock.h"

namespace AccurateClock {

    Time::Time(const timespec &timeValue) : timeValue(timeValue) {
    }

    double Time::getTotalMilliseconds() const {
        const double oneThousand = 1000;
        auto milliseconds =
                (timeValue.tv_sec * oneThousand) +
                (timeValue.tv_nsec / oneThousand);
        return milliseconds;
    }

    void Time::print(std::ostream &out) const {
        const double oneThousand = 1000;
        auto milliseconds = getTotalMilliseconds();
        auto secondsPart = (long)(milliseconds / oneThousand);
        auto millisecondsPart = (long)(milliseconds - (secondsPart * oneThousand));
        auto nsPart = (long)(
                (milliseconds * oneThousand) -
                (secondsPart * oneThousand * oneThousand) -
                (millisecondsPart * oneThousand));
        out << secondsPart << "sec, " << millisecondsPart << "ms, " << nsPart << "ns since the computer booted";
    }



    const Duration Time::operator-(const Time &a) const {
        auto difference = getTotalMilliseconds()
                          - a.getTotalMilliseconds();

        auto duration = Duration(difference);

        return duration;
    }

    const Time DefaultClock::getTime() {
        auto value = timespec();
        clock_gettime(_CLOCK_REALTIME, &value);
        auto time = Time(value);
        return time;
    }

    Duration::Duration(double value) : valueInMilliseconds(value) {
    }

    void Duration::print(std::ostream &out) const {
        out << valueInMilliseconds << "ms";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling with C++11 or higher turned on?

Comment: It could be that you're not passing the correct `-std` flag to the compiler.

Comment: I'm not sure which version, my command line input is 
`gcc -o main main.cc`
the code i posted is one of the header files in my main

Comment: By the way, you want `g++` for C++, not `gcc`.

Comment: I tried with three different, gcc, g++, and gpp. with all three, I'm getting the same error. when I type just g++ to check the version, it gives me an error that it could not be found, even after reinstalling it, twice. so I stuck with gcc and gpp

Comment: @ArkhamWarfare What version of gcc do you have?  Try addding `-std=c++11` to the build command

Comment: I have version 5.4.0-6 for gcc. and by adding to the command, u mean adding to my compile command? or seperately?

Comment: Yes, `gcc -std=c++11 -o main main.cc`

Comment: here's something strange just happened, when i put in the command `gcc  -std=c++11 -c main.cc` i only get 2 errors, `DefaultClock.cpp: In member function ‘const AccurateClock::Time AccurateClock::DefaultClock::getTime()’:
DefaultClock.cpp:41:23: error: ‘_CLOCK_REALTIME’ was not declared in this scope
         clock_gettime(_CLOCK_REALTIME, &value);
                       ^
` when i put int `gcc -o -std=c++11 main main.cc` i get the same errors as before

Comment: same thing, when i switch places between, the -o and the -std command, i only get two errors, different erros

Comment: @ArkhamWarfare Well, in your code, you don't really see where `_CLOCK_REALTIME` is defined... Plus, you shouldn't be starting macro names with an underscore, since they are global.

Comment: Yoo, you're totally right, I changed `_CLOCK_REALTIME` and removed the underscore before it but now i get some other errors, `/tmp/ccSXgOzF.o: In function `sysWrite(int, char*, long)':
main.cc:(.text+0x3b6): undefined reference to `my_open(char*, int)'` and more like this
https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/a93f3459-fefa-41d2-85c4-7344ba5076ec.png